# Why is a different zsh used when I manually ssh vs ssh inside a script file?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ssh, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have a `deploy.sh` file that I would like to run from my local macbook that will `ssh` into a remote Ubuntu 22 server and run a few commands there. Example here:

```bash
#!/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh

main() {
  scp \
    on_server.sh \
    # other files \ 
    "$remote_location:/correct/location"

  ssh $remote_location "cd correct/location; echo $SHELL; ./on_server.sh"
}

main "$@"
```

The `on_server.sh` file has a couple commands using `pnpm` and `pm2`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/zsh

pnpm i
pnpm build

pm2 restart app_name
```

If I ssh manually into my server, `cd` into the right place, and run those `pnpm` & `pm2` commands everything is fine. When my `deploy.sh` does seemingly the same thing, I get errors that `pnpm` and `pm2` commands are not defined.

However, I noticed that `$SHELL` is different between the two situations.

Manual ssh:

```bash
ssh <remote_location>
...
echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh
```

The output of the `echo $SHELL` from `on_server.sh` above is:

```bash
/bin/zsh
```

I believe this `$SHELL` difference is why my commands are failing. Can someone help me understand why there is this difference in the `$SHELL` value?

Comment: `$SHELL` is expanded *locally* before `ssh` even executes. If you want the value of `$SHELL` on the remote host, use single quotes: `ssh $remote_location 'cd ...; echo $SHELL; ./on_server.sh'`.

Comment: Yes, that does actually, thanks. Changing to single quotes gets the same $SHELL value. I'll make an edit to my question to make that clear.

Comment: `/correct/location` and `correct/location` are two different directories, unless you are logging in as a user that has `/` as its home directory.

Comment: Please dont edit your question into a different one.  Thats not how this site works. Ask a new question with your new problem.  I have rolled it back.

Comment: I'm not aware of a **reliable** way a zsh script can find out the path of the zsh-executable which is running the script. `SHELL` certainly is not necessarily correct, as this is just a variable anyone can change. Why is the location of the executable of importance?  If you want to find differences in the zsh variants, I would query the variable `ZSH_VERSION`. This at least is set by zsh itself on startup.

Comment: Even if you know that the PATH to zsh is the same on both hosts, this does not tell you that in both cases you are running the same zsh version....